# $.ajax callback function is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am just starting to learn JSON where a tutorial from other site uses this code (which I already modified to simplify this):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getdata-button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "json-data.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(){
                alert('a');
                $('#showdata').html(
                    "<p>item1="+data.item1+
                    " item2="+data.item2+
                    " item3="+data.item3+"</p>"
                );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the code for json-data.php

```
<?php
    $item1 = "candy";
    $item2 = "chocolate";
    $item3 = "ice cream";

    //return in JSON format
    echo "{";
    echo "item1: ", json_encode($item1), "\n";
    echo "item2: ", json_encode($item2), "\n";
    echo "item3: ", json_encode($item3), "\n";
    echo "}";
?>
```

The problem is that alert function (for debugging purposes) isn't responding after I have clicked the button (with the id of "getdata-button"). Firebug says that the request is successful and I can see the data from there. No error was found. It is just the callback function is not executing, but why?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Keys and string values must be wrapped in double quotes, and `json_encode()` isn't meant to be used INSIDE a json string, it is meant to output a complete JSON string.

Comment: Gah! Don't do that! You should be building an array in PHP and then just doing `echo json_encode($array)`

Comment: I find http://jsonlint.com very helpful. You should take advantage of the ajax "error" callback too. Also http://www.json.org is good for the theory and syntax.

Comment: Add an `error` function to see if the request is failing.

Comment: I also noticed your `success()` function does not take any arguments, so `data` would not be defined. It should be `success: function(data)`

Comment: @nullability , Yes thanks, I forgot to add `data` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output your JSON correctly.  Replace your PHP with the below

```
$items = array(
    'item1' => $item1,
    'item2' => $item2,
    'item3' => $item3
);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: @fullybaked Thanks, this works perfectly. But is the header really mandatory?

Comment: I wouldn't say mandatory, no. But good practice... Yes, as it informs the browser/client exactly what to expect in the response